# How to replace instance of a class in a tree in python

Tags: python, oop, tree, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying to teach myself python by building a decision tree, and I am having trouble with the pruning. I want to check if removing a random subtree branch increases the tree's accuracy  over my previously learned tree, using the following function:

```
def prune_tree(tree, nodes, validation_examples, old_acc):
    percent_to_try = 0.6
    for n in range(int(percent_to_try*len(nodes))):
        inc = random.randint(0, len(nodes)-1)

        if isinstance(nodes[inc], TreeLeaf):
            nodes.pop(inc)
            continue
        node_to_remove = copy.deepcopy(nodes[inc])
        target_class = node_to_remove.mode

        # print id(nodes[inc])
        nodes[inc] = TreeLeaf(target_class)
        # print id(nodes[inc])
        raw_input()

        new_acc = test_tree(validation_examples, tree)

        if new_acc > old_acc:
            print "The new accuracy is: " + str(new_acc) + "%"
            continue
        else: 
            nodes[inc] = node_to_remove
    return True
```

By printing id(nodes[inc]) before and after I try to replace the instances, I can tell that in memory I am not changing the contents of the instance, but instead declaring a new one and assigning it to that position in the array.

I basically want the reference to the old node to point to this new leaf.

Ideally this should happen by recursively deleting everything under the node that we're deleting, testing the accuracy and either keep going if accuracy increased, or return to the previous state if it wasn't.
How should I go about this?